# Execute done method like in jquery after async finishes

Tags: javascript

is it possible to add on an object a listener?
For example my object does async stuff. After progress finishes
an event should be executed like the done() in jquery...

Example:

```
var Obj = function() {

  this.load = function() {
    // Load something and after finishing fire event "done"
  }

}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.load().done(function(data) {
  // handle data
});
```

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a **promise**.

Sure you need to use the deferred api :

```
var Obj = function(){
   this.load =function(){
     var deferred = = $.Deferred();
     // when the condition load is fufilled
     dfd.resolve(someParameters);
     // if there is an error somewhere
     deferred.reject();

     //you need to return 
     return deferred.promise();
   }
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.load()
  .fail(function(){ /* something went wrong! OMG */ })
  .done(function(data) {
  // handle data
});
```

Have a look at : http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: edited, you need to return a promise in Obj.load or it wont work.